# Windows 8 RTM Final on Macbook Air

Tags: windows-8, macbook-air

If I try to install the Windows 8 RTM Final (from MSDN) on my Macbook Air Mid 2011 using Boot Camp, I get this error:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu

I already formatted the disk with NTFS, removed it, reformatted and more...

Does anyone know to resolve this error?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
What worked for me was to make sure I got the [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) (which I had installed before) boot menu by holding the option key at reboot. I picked the windows install disk (in my case a USB stick), and the installation proceded without the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you format the drive using BootCamp Assistant
After you reboot, choose the BOOTCAMP drive from Windows installer
Delete the drive, create one partition (ignore the error) and click Next

Comment: I tried like this - but it doesn't work.

Comment: Igal: Did you have success with the method you describe, or did you guess it would work?